# Filter Map based on condition in Java

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a Map object

```
public class Employee {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String designation; 
}

Map<Integer, Employee> map = new HashMap<Integer, Employee>();
```

I want to filter the map based on one property in Employee which should match user input given property, say userName.

I am using

```
public List<Employee> getEmployeesByName(String userName) {
    map.entrySet().stream().filter(e-> e.getValue().getName().equals(userName)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

I want the output in `List<Employee>` format. I don't understand why is it in format of `List<Entry<Integer, Employee>>`. What am I missing here?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that illustrates what you have tried. We should be able to copy the code and run it as is without adding anything. This means you should at least have a class with `main()` like any stand alone Java program. Then show the output you get and describe what you want it to be instead.

Comment: That should be `.collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: I have made the corrections

Comment: Change `e-> e.getValue().getName() == userName` to `e-> e.getValue().getName().equals(userName)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be streaming `Map.Entry`s but just want the values. Change `map.stream()` (shouldn't work) to `map.values().stream()`.

Comment: To add to this, `map.stream()` is not possible. Edit: after the edits, he now needs to replace `map.entrySet()` with `map.values()`

Comment: @curiousdev Yeah, thought so, had to go check.